# Live Audio-reaction to external input in Animation nodes?

Tags: animation-nodes, audio

Is it possible to control animation nodes using live audio from external input such as soundcard? (eventually to be able even to perform live with blender)

Answer (score 1):

There is no native support for live audio input. However, you may use a python module like *[python-sounddevice](https://python-sounddevice.readthedocs.io)* to get the input sound from a device and use the data inside of Animation Nodes. Consult the [documentation](https://animation-nodes-manual.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/subprograms/script.html) to know how to use a python module like this in Animation Nodes.

Comment: Okay, will see what I can come up with. Thanks.